using ansible , there are 2 servers in aws but cannot connect 2nd server
Using ansible, there are 2 servers one is ansible and other is target server.
I have created file in all servers from ansible server but i cannot ssh into target to see the file is creayted or not. However,there is not any error from ansiblr server.
I tried ssh -i privae-key ubuntu@public-id-target-server
but cannot connect to target sever using ssh  to check if files is created or not

Please edit your question and add your code, inventory, specify what exactly you get on running the playbook and what happens if you try to ssh into the target servers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
